# Schedule the deployment of a sagemaker model

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying out SageMaker and I've created a model using autopilot. The point is that SageMaker only allows you to deploy directly to an endpoint. But since I'll only be using the model a couple of times a day, what is the most direct way to  schedule deployments by events (for example when loading new csv's into an s3 directory or when I see a queue in sqs) or at least periodically?

Comment: what about CloudWatch events?

Answer (score 1):

The answer above is incorrect. Boto3 is part of the Lambda Python environment, so all you need to do is create a SageMaker client and invoke the appropriate API.

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker.html

Comment: Schedule a Lambda function in cloudwatch events https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use a trigger (e.g. Cloudwatch Events/EventBridge, S3 event, etc.) to run a Lambda function that deploys your SageMaker model. The Lambda function, however, requires a runtime that can call SageMaker APIs. You will have to create a custom runtime (via Layers) for that. If you're using Python, use this as reference: https://dev.to/vealkind/getting-started-with-aws-lambda-layers-4ipk.